# select the latest balance for each product based on store (SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying  to get latest balance for each product based on storeid . But I don know why get result  duplicate stock name `sasi`.

**Sql Query**

```
select stockname, balance,updatedat,storename,s1.productid,s1.storeid
from stockmovement s1
inner join (select storeid, productid, max(updatedat) as maxdate
            from stockmovement
            group by storeid,productid) s2
on s2.storeid = s1.storeid and s2.maxdate = s1.updatedat
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query using row_number():

```
select stockname, balance, bupdatedat, storename,productid,storeid from 
(
  select stockname, balance, bupdatedat, storename,productid,storeid, row_number() over 
  (partition by storeid,productid order by bupdatedat date desc) rn
)t where rn=1
```

Comment: i have some issues like product:A Balance:10 Date:2021-03-18 09:01:00 storeid:1 , product:B Balance:6 Date:2021-03-18 09:01:00 storeid:1 and product:A Balance:12 Date:2021-03-18 10:01:00 storeid:1. currently using your query result is product:A Balance:10 and product:B Balance:6 but expected result is product:A Balance:12 and product:B Balance:6

Comment: If you need the latest balance than i have revised my answer.

Comment: yes I want get latest balance . Thank you so much

Comment: You are most welcome. Please let me know if you face any more difficulties with this query. Best wishes.

Comment: i using this query but still facing the problems

Comment: same date but diff time cannot

Comment: Can you please share input statement so that i can recreate the situation?

Comment: Is the name of datetime field bupdatedat?@

Comment: if bupdatedat is the field of datetime type the queery shoud work.

Comment: That's great. Best wishes.

Comment: Do you know how to solve this problems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66686274/get-the-stock-transfer-location-and-balance-inventory

Comment: Let me have a look.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem, and they can be solved efficiently using [`distinct on ()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) in Postgres:

```
select distinct on (storeid, productid) *
from stockmovement
order by storeid, productid, updatedat desc
```

This is typically faster than the equivalent solution using window functions.

Comment: It's surely the smartest answer. :)

Comment: this answer no valid . i only want select particular columns not all (* )

Comment: @sy523: well then replace `*` with the columns you want.

Comment: i have some issues like product:A Balance:10 Date:2021-03-18 09:01:00 storeid:1 , product:B Balance:6 Date:2021-03-18 09:01:00 storeid:1 and product:A Balance:12 Date:2021-03-18 10:01:00 storeid:1. currently using your query
result is product:A Balance:10 and product:B Balance:6  but expected result is product:A Balance:12 and product:B Balance:6

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1):

```
select stockname, balance, updatedat, storename,productid,storeid from 
(
  select stockname, balance, updatedat, storename,productid,storeid, row_number() over 
  (partition by storeid,productid order by updatedat desc )rn from stockmovement
)t where rn=1
```