# get the stock transfer location and balance (Inventory)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm facing some issues regarding show the stock transfer location from and to because I only have one column for record the location in my database table.  Thanks for who can help me solve the problems.

currently I using this query below:

```
Select *  from stockmovement where documentno IS NOT NULL ;
```

This image is my database table.[image: This image is my database table.]

But Expected Result I want is this image below:[image]

Comment: Please share data in text format so that I can regenerate the situation.

Comment: What's the logic behind selecting from warehouse? Rows with stock in status?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1i1tE0TpDlHnghE5GzUG7fmO2nplErMuYItls3w8r1Gg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: First, a stock movement table without a date/time indicator just seems very off.  Second, please explain the logic for the expected result.  It is not obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Is it what are you looking for:

```
Select stock_name ,balance receive_balance,
(select max(location) from stockmovement s 
where s.stock_name=sv.stock_name and documentno is null and status='stock in') from_warehouse, location to_warehouse,documentno
from stockmovement sv where documentno is not null
```

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "from"
LINE 3:  and status='stock in') from storename,documentno from stock..

Comment: from location to,documentno from stockmovement  i think cannot

Comment: Please check now. Since from and to are reserve key words that's why those are creating syntax error. It's ok now.

Comment: is working. Thank you so much for solved this question.

Comment: You are most welcome. If it helped please accept the answer. Best wishes.